How to get selected columns with repository pattern?
I want to create generic method to get few columns only. I am using entity framework with repository pattern.
I tried with below
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetSelectedColumns<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> selector,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(predicate);
        }
        return await query.Select(selector).ToListAsync();

    }

I am getting compile time error as below
Error  CS1061  'IEnumerable<TResult>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<TResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Please note; I have already included reference for Microsoft.EntityFramework
What else I am missing? is this correct way to get few columns using entity framework?

EntityFramework deals with "entities"; which you can then query further to project to anonymous types (with fewer columns).

Simple, don't use a generic repository (anti)pattern, EF already provides this via the DbSet<T>.  If you want an abstraction to make it easier to test, have your Repository return IQueryable<T>. As for the error, the Select method that EF is resolving is not the standard EF Linq method. That one does not return IEnumerable so I'd almost suspect it is resolving to a custom or 3rd party extension method.

Change type of the selector parameter to Expression<Func<T, TResult>>.  But why not simply expose the DbSet<TEntity> as an IQueryable<TEntity>?
